# Zoom in high resolution image in a presentation

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, microsoft-powerpoint, zoom

I have an image of global view of the Moon. I have a second one which is from a different camera, very high res of an area few kilometers in size. During a presentation I want to zoom in from a global view into a local feature I want to show. Something like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/space/comments/48j67s/zooming_out_of_hubbles_extreme_deep_field/).

PowerPoint doesn't look to be smart enough for that. Prezi offers a lot of unnecessary material for me. I just need regular slides and one highly customized slide. I guess I need to make an animation? Software suggestions? Needs to be quick and easy to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to my mind.

1. Make some animated segments using for example [Blender](https://www.blender.org/).

One program that is really interesting to use videos (or other media) as slides is [SlideDog](https://slidedog.com/) that has a free version. You then can have a stage of the zoom as a slide on this program.

2. A program that has a similar metaphor (zooming) as Prezi is [Focusky](http://focusky.com/). It also has a free version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all the steps in between the macro and micro images in the zoom.

If, as suggested above, you use Blender, then the beginning and ending states (keyframes) would be created by the software and it would know what they are composed of and how to create the zoom.

If they are static pixelated images, then using a video editor of sufficiently good quality could do a blur zoom between the two keyframes so that you can't see the initial image losing quality.

This is not quite what you want but you get the idea: [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgaAqdExEmM

Answer (score 0):

> PowerPoint doesn't look to be smart enough for that.

Use the PowerPoint Morph transition to zoom.

For example:

1. Create a slide with the global view of the Moon.
2. Use whatever technique you want to highlight the area that you want to zoom in on.

   For example, animate temporary crosshairs that draw attention to the area, and then "leave behind" a semi-opaque rectangle (or whatever shape you want).
3. Duplicate the slide with the Moon and highlighted area.
4. Group the Moon and the highlighted area on that slide.
5. Duplicate that slide.
6. On the new duplicate, enlarge the group so that it is bigger than the slide, and move it so that the highlighted area is at the center of the slide.
7. Apply the Morph transition.

   Preview the transition: it should zoom in smoothly from the "global" view (the previous slide) to the close-up. Adjust the duration of the transition as you see fit.
8. Create a new slide showing the local feature at that area.
9. Apply a "Fly-through" transition, or what transition you feel is most suitable.

I wrote this procedure not knowing what the local feature image looks like. If the local feature image is simply a more detailed "tile" of the global view, from essentially the same viewpoint, then I would adjust the procedure to skip the perhaps-unnecessary "fly-through" (or similar) transition (from the close-up of the global view to the local feature): I'd experiment by overlaying that detailed tile, appropriately reduced in size, on its corresponding location on the global view. Then I'd group those elements, duplicate that slide, and enlarge the group until the detailed area occupied the slide area (with the global view now much bigger than the slide). Then apply Morph to get the "zoom" effect.

Comment: For examples of using the Morph transition to zoom, see this video that I created in PowerPoint: "[The Lifecycle of an IMS Connect Transaction](https://youtu.be/ygG9D6mfLDA)" (in particular, the panning'n'zooming from 9 minutes 15 seconds onwards).